# Android Geth failed to connect to main net

Tags: go-ethereum, android, mobile-wallet

Following the Android sample code from [Mobile Client](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes), along with latest `geth.aar` fetched from [Go Ethereum Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) (stable release 1.7.3 and development release 1.8.0). I am not able to connect to main net with either of the release. On Android display all I see is:

```
My name: GethDroid/v1.8.0-unstable/android-arm64/go1.9.2
My address: [::]:40039
My protocols: [les]

Latest block: 0, syncing...
```

Tested on Nexus 5X (Android 8.1.0, API 27).

Did I miss something?

Comment: I got the same issue. Following @willjgriff I left it to run for a day and nothing happened. Has anyone solved it yet?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28349)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add "android.permission.INTERNET" permisssion in androidmsnifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you left it to run for a while? I built an Android light client wallet with Geth a while ago and it could take up to an hour, sometimes longer, to find peers and begin syncing.

If it's of any help it's on Github [here](https://github.com/willjgriff/android-ethereum-wallet), although it's written in Kotlin. And specifically I start a node in the same way the doc you've sent suggests as can be seen [here](https://github.com/willjgriff/android-ethereum-wallet/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/github/willjgriff/ethereumwallet/ethereum/node/DomainNode.kt)